# Vim-latex: forward and reverse search

Tags: forward-inverse-search, vim-latex

I've been trying to get vim and Okular to talk to each other with forward and reverse search.

I have

```
vim --servername GVIM --remote-silent +%1 %f
```

in my Okular editor configuration. When I run vim with `vim --servername GVIM`
shift-clicking in Okular causes the following error to appear in vim:

```
E492: Not an editor command: %1|cal foreground()|if &im|star|en|redr|f
```

Random error text sometimes also appears in the LaTeX document I'm trying to edit, but this hasn't been happening lately.
I also have in my `~/.vim/ftplugin/tex.vim`

```
let g:Tex_CompileRule_dvi = 'latex -src-specials -interaction=nonstopmode $*'
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo, change number `1` for the letter `l`:

`gvim --servername GVIM --remote-silent +%l %f`

Comment: Wow, thanks! This isn't the first time in recent history I've mistaken ls for 1s, you'd think I'd have learned by now.

Comment: It happens, they are terribly similar :)
Please accept the answer to mark the question as solved.